# Why the VC dimension to this linear hypothesis equal to 3?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, model-selection, vc-theory

I am trying hard to understand this. Here is the scenario:

```
X = R^2
H = { h(x) = x + 10 }
```

I need to calculate the VC dimension for the above linear separator. Somehow, the VC dimension for this linear separator is 3. I just cannot understand how.

According to what I understand, VC dimension is the size of the largest finite subset of `X` which can be shattered by `h`. So if there exists a subset of size `n` where all points are shattered by `h` and there exists a subset of size `n+1` where at least one point is not shattered by `h`, then the VC dimension will be `n`.

- Is the VC dimension >= 1?

> Yes. We just need to pretend there is a single point on the line and by keeping the line (X-axis) steady we can flip which side is positive/negative

- Is the VC dimension >= 2?

> Yes, because we could separate all 4 combinations { ++, --, +-, -+ } using a single line

- Is the VC dimension >= 3?

> This should be NO, according to what I understand. How could we separate this case `+ - +`?

But I was going through a [video, that explains VC dimensions](https://youtu.be/W2utwvbN1sY) which says it is three and I do not understand how.

Comment: I thought they explained it quite well (at about 2:30 in the video). I think the key is to remember that you only have to shatter *just one* specific set of $d$ points in order for the VC-dimension to be greater or equal to $d$ ($d=3$ in this case). You don't have to shatter any combination of points (e.g. you can't shatter $+-+$ if they are on a line but it doesn't matter because you can shatter a different set of points if they form a triangle as in the video!)

Answer (score 2):

The VC dimension for the classifier depends on the dimension of space that your data points belong to.

In your problem, if your mean $x\in \mathbb{R^2}$, then the VC dimension is 3. For $\mathbb{R^2}$, you can always shatter any three general position points ("general position" means they do not coincidentally lie on the same line). For instance, consider three points `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)`. No matter how you assign labels to them, you can always seperate them by a line. If you consider point points with label `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)` with label `[+,-,-,+]`, this is the "xor" case which cannot be seperated by a line.

For $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then the VC dimension is 2 because you cannot separate `+-+`.

In general for $x\in \mathbb{R^d}$, the VC dimension for a linear classifier is $d+1$.

Comment: But how do we separate `+-+` for `x ∈ ℝ`?

Comment: in $\mathbb{R}^2$ do don't consider the case where the three points lie on the same line. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The VC dimension depends on the dimension of your data and on the family of functions you are evaluating.

In $\mathbb R^2$, the VC dimesion of the family $h(x)$ of oriented lines is 3 beacause, with oriented lines, you can only classify correctly three points taking into account all the 8 possible label assignments, as depicted in the figure below:

[image]

Figure from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/svmtutorial.pdf

Yor family of functions $h(x) = x + 10$ is a subset of the family of lines, then the VC is 3, you can try to draw the same figure as the one above but whith your particular $h(x)$. You won't be able to separate 4 points taking into account their 16 possible labelings with this family of functions.