# Is there any way to explicitly measure the complexity of a Machine Learning Model in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, r, predictive-modeling, model-selection

I'm interested in [model debugging](https://debug-ml-iclr2019.github.io/), and one of the points that it mentions is to compare your model with a "less complex" one to check if the performance is substantially better on the most complex model as compared with the simpler one.

So, it raises my questions:

Suppose you have a [Ensemble model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) and a [Linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_model) for a classification task
*"It seems natural to think that the ensemble model is more complex than the linear model"*

1. What would it be a model's agnostic way to numerically measure its complexity to compare two or more models in such terms?
2. Is there any Python/R implementation that can help with such a task?

Comment: There are several breeds of "complexity".  Memory and Compute are popular.  Cyclomatic complexity also counts.  There is a difference between "the code you type" and the load on the system.  If memory gets big enough that swap is required your read/write can go into the basement.  You might also consider things like Akaike Information Criterion (and derivatives) for model selection. Some ML uses uint8 or uint4 instead of float64, and that counts for speed, memory, and model accuracy.  How do you account for that?

Comment: @Moreno could you please add some comment to explain what else you are looking for.

Comment: My answer is complexity understood as interpretability (the degree of human understanding of a model). It might be the case that the OP is looking for memory and computational complexity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not heard of any model agnostic way to measure model complexity. There are several strategies but they are model dependant.

You can tackle the problem using different families of models.

- For **linear models** you can count the number of nonzero parameters that is using. Number of features used for the prediction.
- For **decision tree** you can count the maximum depth that the tree achieves.
- For **Neural Networks** you can count the number of parameters that your NN is optimizing.
- For **ensemble methods** (random forest, gradient boosting) you can use an aggregation of the different weak learners used in the model.

For the python implementation there are several implementations depending on for which model you want to measure it. Some of them if you notice are really easy to measure.

Its intuitively hard to compare complexity between different model families. What is more complex a linear regression with 4 coefficients or a decision tree with max_depth=3?

On the topic of deep learning complexity, Hinton, Oriol, Jeff Dean published a paper [Distilling the knowledge of a Neural Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02531.pdf). Where they talk about simplifying the complexity of a Neural Network.

Comment: Why just the nonzero parameters in linear models?

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, "complexity" is a loaded term in computer science. Normally, complexity is measured in "big-O notation" and has to do with how solutions scale in time as the number of inputs grows. For example, [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444870/what-is-the-computational-complexity-of-a-1d-convolutional-layer) discusses the computational complexity of convolutional layers.

In deep learning, however, competing neural network architectures are generally applying the same algorithm (back-propagation) to the same types of problems (e.g., ImageNet classification); the only difference is the architecture. Further, most architectures use similar computational elements (e.g., convolutional layers and linear layers). Thus, it is a convention to use the *number of parameters* as a stand-in for complexity. It is true that this is only an approximation: two networks may have the same number of parameters but require different numbers of operations. But it's generally a good approximation, given that different architectures generally have the similarities noted above, but can have sizes that differ by several orders of magnitude.

As a reference, consider Figure 1 in the [EfficientNet Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.11946.pdf). They use the number of trainable parameters as a stand-in for "model size" and note that the number of parameters is more-or-less linearly correlated with runtime.

As for a Python function that counts the number of trainable parameters, this will depend whether you are using Keras, Tensorflow, PyTorch, etc. In Keras, this is one line: `model.count_params()`. In PyTorch, you can calculate it from `model.parameters()` as discussed [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-do-i-check-the-number-of-parameters-of-a-model/4325).

Answer (score 2):

It's perhaps a bit naive but the first idea that comes to mind is to simply count the number of parameters which have to be estimated during training: the more values need to be estimated, the more complex the model is, since the hypothesis space is larger. For example a linear model needs only $n+1$ parameters (with $n$ the number of features), whereas the number of parameters in an ensemble model needs is the sum of the numbers of parameters for every learner, so it's likely to be higher. This idea could be refined to take  into account the range of values of a parameter.

As a very rough approximation, one could simply calculate the size of the object which represents the model in python (assuming the representation of the model is space-efficient, it might not always be the case).

Comment: i think its a great approach but it will only work with Linear Models, a decision tree will have to be evaluate something different. I have not heard for any model agnostic way to evaluate models

Comment: For the size of the objects I am not so sure if it will work. How can you compare models from different families?  A decision tree vs a linear model, they way they get saved is different

Comment: There's Rademacher Complexity and VC dimension, which are common methods to measure complexity in machine learning theory. Neither is very useful in practice though. Check out the book "Foundations of Machine Learning" for a nice introduction, or "a probabilistic theory of pattern recognition" if you really really love math and want all the details.

Comment: @CarlosMougan the equivalent idea with decision trees would be to count the number of nodes in the tree, but I agree that this method is very crude and any comparison between different families of models would be potentially biased. Imho it depends what the goal is: for a big-picture comparison between models it can give a decent idea of how two models compare, but for a fine-grained comparison it's way too simplistic of course.

Comment: @AndreasMueller sounds interesting, you should write an answer about this.

Comment: @Erwan yes, I think we are on the same page on this topic.

Comment: I would love to hear @AndreasMueller answer to the topic, it seems to be a great way to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

One option is [Bayesian information criterion (BIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) which is a model selection criterion that attempts to rewards modeling fit, as measured by maximizing likelihood, while penalizing the number of parameters.

One implementation of BIC is in the [`RegscorePy`](https://pypi.org/project/RegscorePy/.) package.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by other answers here, when we talk about model complexity we are usually thinking about the number of parameters the model learns. When someone talks about comparing to a less complex model, they often mean comparing to an intuitively less complex model (either a model in the same class, e.g. a neural network with fewer neurons, or a model from a simpler class, e.g. a linear model rather than a random forest).

One way to think about model complexity between very different models is [Kolmogorov Complexity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), and you can approximate this by looking at the amount of space occupied by your saved (e.g. pickled) models. In the example you gave, the ensemble would occupy more disk space than the linear model, unless the ensemble was simpler than the linear model (e.g. an ensemble of two linear models with 10 learned coefficients each versus a linear model with 200 learned coefficients).

Answer (score 2):

**1. But, what would it be a way to numerically measure the model's complexity in order to be able to compare two or more models in such terms?**

You can use the VC dimension to measure the complexity of a model in a numerical format.
See [Vapnik–Chervonenkis dimension on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension#:%7E:text=In%20Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis%20theory%2C%20the,a%20statistical%20binary%20classification%20algorithm.&text=A%20much%20simpler%20alternative%20is%20to%20threshold%20a%20linear%20function).

**2. Is there any python implementation that can help with such a task?**

There is already a stack exchange link that explains about VC dimension.
[How to calculate VC-dimension?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16140/how-to-calculate-vc-dimension)

Comment: It will be appreciated if you can cite some of the most important information from the links you posted, just in case the sites go missing or the content changes